# Slow oracle query being used in a tcl script

Tags: oracle, query-performance

I have written this query to be used by orasql and orafetch in a tcl script. The query is nested into a proc that is run as many times as a date range given needs it to be run (usually around 3 times per instance). The tables with $YYYYMM are full month tables consisting of about 13 million rows. The $advocate variable will pull about 39 different account_ids which will reduce the number of rows returned substantially but not great as great as claim_status_code='4' (~460,000 rows). I have no idea what the current run-time of the query is because I have no allowed it to run longer than about 30 mins. I really need this to pull in a couple of seconds, I am just way to new to all of this to know how to improve the speed. I have looked at oracle documentation over optimizing queries and I have tried incorporate those suggestions into what I have written. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

```
select 
    case
        when clg_payor_id
        is null
        then payor_id1
        else clg_payor_id
    end
    , count(unique era_id||invoice) count
from marge.e835_clp_$YYYYMM@e835v2
where claim_status_code='4' and payor_id1!='client'
group by case when clg_payor_id is null then payor_id1 else clg_payor_id end, era_id
having era_id 
in (
    select era_id 
    from marge.e835_checks_$YYYYMM@e835v2 
    where input_date between '$date1' and '$date2' 
    group by account_id, era_id
    having account_id 
    in (
        select ea.account_id 
        from cowboy.enrolled_submitters es
        , cowboy.enrolled_accounts ea 
        where ea.submitter_id=es.submitter_id 
        and es.advocate='$advocate'
     )
) 
order by count desc
```

UPDATE: As suggested, I have moved the era_id out of the HAVING clause and into the WHERE. When I run this query, it returns a lot of unwanted results because of all of the account_id's but I can't figure out why. The query did actually run though and it only took ~9 secs. So much improved.

```
select
    case
        when clg_payor_id
        is null
        then payor_id1
        else clg_payor_id
    end
    , account_id, count(unique era_id||invoice) count
from marge.e835_clp_$YYYYMM@e835v2
where claim_status_code='4' 
and payor_id1!='client' 
and era_id
in (
    select era_id
    from marge.e835_checks_$YYYYMM@e835v2
    where input_date between '$date1' and '$date2'
    group by account_id
        , era_id
    having account_id
        in (
            select ea.account_id
            from cowboy.enrolled_submitters es
            , cowboy.enrolled_accounts ea
            where ea.submitter_id=es.submitter_id
            and es.advocate='$advocate'
        )
)
group by case when clg_payor_id is null then payor_id1 else clg_payor_id end, account_id
order by count desc
```

Comment: What is the query plan?  It looks like you are referencing local tables as well as tables in a different database over a database link, is that right?

Comment: I don't have a good enough understanding of it to list a query plan. But yes, I believe you are correct.

Comment: Why are you referencing non-aggregate columns in a `having` clause?

Comment: Try putting the `era_id in (...` condition in your `WHERE` clause and post the explain plan here.

Comment: @Rachcha I was trying to filter using the having clause as suggested by the oracle documentation I read. I don't know how to run an explain plan. What I see on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Rachcha Moving the era_id brought it down to 9 seconds. Much improved. Thank you.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I have no idea. But that was why it stalled. I suppose no other optimization help can be offered until I have an explain plan.

Comment: @TylerChristian There is some considerations to you look at. The implicit convertions is very painfull, you should check theese parts:  `claim_status_code='4'` if this column is number you are doing an implicit conversion you should put `claim_status_code=4` instead (if it is varchar it is ok). Also this date checks `input_date between '$date1' and '$date2'` you should change that to  `input_date between to_date('$date1','WHATEVERYOURFORMATIS') and to_date('$date2','WHATEVERYOURFORMATIS')` see if that can help a little more.